# Handling specific personalised exceptions / conditions ( FastAPI , Pydantic Models , Prediction Model deployment )

Tags: python, validation, exception, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using **Pydantic models** for data validation with **FastAPI** to deploy a **Machine Learning model for predictions**, so I want to handle the following exceptions / conditions :

- Giving many inputs if one of them doesn't match the features requirements (types, length...) throw an exception for that specific invalid input but show outputs of the other valid inputs

**What I want to achieve**

Inputs :

```json
    [
      {
        "name":"John",
        "age": 20,
        "salary": 15000
      },
      {
        "name":"Emma",
        "age": 25,
        "salary": 28000
      },
      {
        "name":"David",
        "age": "test",
        "salary": 50000
      },
      {
        "name":"Liza",
        "age": 5000,
        "salary": 30000
      }
    ]
```

Outputs :

```json
    [
      {
        "prediction":"Class1",
        "probability": 0.88
      },
      {
        "prediction":"Class0",
        "probability": 0.79
      },
      {
      "ËRROR: Expected type int but got str instead"
      },
      {
      "ËRROR: invalid age number"
      }
    ]
```

**What I have with my base model classes :**

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from typing import List

n_inputs = 3
n_outputs = 2


class Inputs(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    salary: float


class InputsList(BaseModel):
    inputs: List[Inputs]

    @validator("inputs", pre=True)
    def check_dimension(cls, v):
        for point in v:
            if len(point) != n_inputs:
                raise ValueError(f"Input data must have a length of {n_inputs} features")

        return v


class Outputs(BaseModel):
    prediction: str
    probability: float

class OutputsList(BaseModel):
    output: List[Outputs]

    @validator("output", pre=True)
    def check_dimension(cls, v):
        for point in v:
            if len(point) != n_outputs:
                raise ValueError(f"Output data must a length of {n_outputs}")

        return v
```

**My question is :**
-> How can I achieve this kind of exception or condition handling with my code above ?

Comment: If you want API to return a message you can't just raise an error ( which will terminate the execution) but instead return a string of the message you want to convey. so it should be some if-elif-else construct.

Comment: @pavel Thank you for your answer, can you write an example that matches my situation?

Comment: try to cast your input to int

Comment: @Unreboot I need to respect inputs types to hand them to the model correctly ( as it was trained for )

Comment: @python_user u have any idea how to use this for a list of inputs?

Comment: This is currently not possible to solve through regular pydantic validation, so you'll have to retrieve the whole structure as JSON (`request: Request`, `input_list = await request.json()`) then go through the list and attempt to create a pydantic model for each element manually: https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/2274 - that way you can use pydantic's validation, but still handle invalid elements in your list.

Comment: can you post an example of the implementation as an answer to my problem above? cuz I didn't really get how to implement it here @MatsLindh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by decoding the submitted JSON and handling the list yourself. You can then catch the `ValidationError` raise by Pydantic when there's a mismatch between expected and submitted data types.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator, ValidationError, conint
from typing import List

app = FastAPI()


class Inputs(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: conint(lt=130)
    salary: float
    
   
@app.post("/foo")
async def create_item(request: Request):
    input_list = await request.json()
    outputs = []
    
    for element in input_list:
        try:
            read_input = Inputs(**element)
            outputs.append(f'{read_input.name}: {read_input.age * read_input.salary}')
        except ValidationError as e:
            outputs.append(f'Invalid input: {e}')
    
    return outputs
```

Submitting your list to the `/foo` endpoint generates (in this case) a list of processed values or an error:

```
['John: 300000.0', 
 'Emma: 700000.0', 
 'Invalid input: 1 validation error for Inputs\nage\n  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)', 
 'Invalid input: 1 validation error for Inputs\nage\n  ensure this value is less than 130 (type=value_error.number.not_lt; limit_value=130)'
]
```

Comment: thank you sooo much for your feedback, can u please tell me how u did submit your list to the /foo endpoint, because Idk how we give inputs using Request request

Comment: Using any http client that can submit JSON would work; I simply copied your list into a python-repl, `data = [{"name":"John", ... etc.}]` then `requests.post('http://localhost:8000/foo', json=data)`